# Does the modified Szpiro conjecture require minimal model?

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, elliptic-curves

The modified Szpiro conjecture is described in
[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Szpiro_conjecture)
and [here](http://modular.math.washington.edu/mcs/archive/Fall2001/notes/12-10-01/12-10-01/node2.html) and [here](http://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Szpiro%27s_conjecture).

> The modified Szpiro conjecture states that: given $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists a constant $C(\varepsilon)$ such that for any elliptic curve $E$ defined over $\mathbb{Q}$ with invariants $c4, c6$ and conductor $f$, we have

$$\max\{ \vert c_4 \vert^3, \vert c_6\vert^2\} \leq C(\varepsilon )\cdot f^{6+\varepsilon } $$

The original Szpiro conjecture requires minimal model, while
the modified one appears to doesn't require minimal model.

> Does the modified Szpiro conjecture require minimal model?
>
> Does the modified Szpiro conjecture allow $a_1 \ne 0$ and/or $a_3 \ne 0$?
>
> Reference for it and other names?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The conductor **does not** depend on the model. The $c_4$ and $c_6$ do. In fact as $E$ varies among the different integral models for the same elliptic curve, the left-hand side of the inequality differs by an arbitrary $12$-th power of an integer. The conjecture certainly allows for $a_1 \ne 0$ and $a_3 \ne 0$. If we impose $a_1=a_3=0$ we can get a model that is close to being minimal, and then the left-hand side is multiplied by a bounded factor that can be absorbed into the $C(\epsilon)$.

In fact, the conjecture still makes sense if you restrict to models for the form
$$
Y^2=X^3+AX+B, \qquad A,B \in \mathbb{Z}, \qquad 4A^3+27B^2 \ne 0
$$ 
assuming that the model satisfies the following minimality condition: there is no integer $u>1$ such that $u^4 \mid A$ and $u^6 \mid B$. In this case you can write the conjecture in the form
$$
\max(A^3,B^2) \le C^\prime(\epsilon) \cdot f^{6+\epsilon}.
$$
The $C^\prime(\epsilon)$ has to differ slightly from $C(\epsilon)$ to take account of the fact the model is not entirely minimal at $2$ and $3$. It is an easy exercise to translate between the version the OP gives for minimal models and the version I give for short Weierstrass models (that satisfy the stated minimality condition).

Comment: Thanks. So the quoted conjecture from Wikipedia and the other sources is wrongly stated?

Comment: "Wrongly stated" is a little harsh. I would say that the minimality condition is implicit.